Why are some orbits circular and others elliptical
My understanding is: Due to the inverse square law, the farther away an object is from the sun, the less gravitational pull it has on it.  Depending on what its velocity is, under the influence of the sun’s gravity and the law of conservation of angular momentum, its orbit will end up being either an ellipse or a circle (special case of ellipse).
Although I don’t really know how these all interact together to result in either a circular or elliptical orbit

Have you ever seen any illustrations of Newton's cannonball analogy?  I think it's a pretty elegant thought experiment.  It might illustrate what you're unclear on, though you could be more explicit about what part confuses you.

Unfortunally, Wikipedia articles about this are too wordy and not very basic, at least in English... Canonball example by Erin Anne is good, and probably the simplest. It should be understood also that orbit depends not only the value of velocity but also on the direction of the velocity vector, and orbit depends on starting point also. The same velocity value 7.5 km/s on height 400 km over Earth can result in circular orbit, slightly eliptical orbit, or fall to the atmosphere, depending on direction of velocity.

An orbiting body has six degrees of freedom, so you need six constraints in order to describe its orbit. In other words, just the velocity vector isn't enough information to narrow down to one orbit - there are infinitely many orbits sharing the same velocity vector at different locations. If you look at what happens when you have the same velocity but at different points in space, or different velocities at the same point, you might be able to pick out differences between more and less eccentric orbits.

OMG, that illustration really helped.

...Continue:  the same velocity 7.5 km/s at height 2000 km over Earth surface will result in highly elliptical orbit, or in fall to the atmosphere, depending on the velocity direction. And at height 40000 km the same velocity 7.5 km/s will result in escape from Earth or - you can guess - fall to Earth's atmosphere, depending on the velocity direction.

You might like my orbit diagrams here https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/676872/123208 There's also a script there you can edit to make your own diagrams.

This might sound absurd, but there's a game called "Kerbal Space Program" that has in it a tool to help plan orbit changes.  There's probably a million hours of tutorial videos on Youtube of how to do orbits in that game.  It isn't a perfect analogy to the real world, but for starting with understanding orbits and changing orbits it's pretty good.  Unfortunately for me, I got my aerospace engineering degree a decade before it came out.

All orbits are elliptical. A circular orbit is only a very special case of an ellipse with the semi mayor and the semi minor axes are equal. There is no moon or planet within our solar system with a circular orbit. The probability of a exact circular orbit is extremely small.

Please read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbit

MinhHuynh - "that illustration really helped"  In the third illustration you can see that the ball is in an elliptical orbit, it is closer to the ground when on the opposite side of the Earth. Now imagine that the cannonball is shot at even higher velocity from the mountain, the orbit would be circular.  It has to be shot at exactly the right speed though, if they shoot it too hard it will be elliptical again, this time with the high point being on the other side of the Earth.

The question seems to be asking if there is something in the general laws that govern orbits which would cause some orbits to be circular. I'm not sure what the close votes are for. It seems like an answerable question, even if the answer is no, with explanations for why many planets and moons seem to wind up in relatively circular orbits, and how spacecraft are able to be placed into relatively circular orbits.
